# Run both bridge and relay & control with nyx

Tags: relays, bridge, ubuntu, nyx

I am attempting to run both a relay and a bridge on the same server. I have gotten it to start with `tor -f /etc/tor1/torrc` but I'm not sure it's staying running, and I'm not sure that'll run on boot. No keys or fingerprint are generated (I am using separate ports for the bridge)

Also, I cannot control the bridge instance using nyx.

**EDIT** I can confirm the second instance of Tor won't stay running. As soon as the output of 'opened or listener' comes, it dies. I however started the second one not via systemd, and the first one I did

Comment: How did you configure your `torrc`? Did you try to start `tor` as a user or per systemd (`systemctl restart tor`)?

Comment: @JensKubieziel I used systemctl restart tor@default. First instance runs as debian-tor. Second instance does not stay running, and can't be controlled via systemd for whatever reason

Comment: You should use multiple Tor instances as described here: https://helpmanual.io/man8/tor-instance-create/
This way you can manage them via `systemd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to follow the guidelines [here](https://helpmanual.io/man8/tor-instance-create/) and get the second instance up and running. Didn't even know you could spawn another daemon

Thanks to everyone!